# Swagger: schema definition for two different objects

Tags: json, swagger

I have to create an API that can return JSON object in two different formats based on the input parameter. Suppose if we pass "report=monthly" in query string the output will be like:

```
[{
    "Month": "Jan",
    "Details": [{
        "userId": 12345,
        "userName": "ABC"
    }]
}, {
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Details": [{
        "userId": 12346,
        "userName": "ABD"
    }]
}]
```

If the above parameter is not passed the output will be like:

```
{
    "Details": [{
        "userId": 12345,
        "userName": "ABC"
    }, {
        "userId": 12346,
        "userName": "ABD"
    }]
}
```

How can I define schema for a single API to return JSON in the above formats? I can not create 2 endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way is to define `Month` as an optional property.

```yaml
paths:
  /report:
    parameters:
      ...
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/ReportEntry'

definitions:
  ReportEntry:
    type: object
    properties:
      Month:
        type: string
        example: Jan
      Details:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/UserInfo'
    required:
      - Details     # <---- "Details" is required, "Month" is optional

  UserInfo:
    type: object
    properties:
      userId:
        type: integer
        example: 12345
      userName:
        type: string
        example: ABC
    required:
      - userId
      - userName
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Helen. That helped!